# How can I refactor this code that tests if multiple array values are inside another arrays specific key?

Tags: php, arrays, refactoring

I have a class which returns rooms. I have a couple methods ( 4-5 ) which all extract "available" parameters the user can specify to this API to return unique results.

In one of these methods, I'm checking if the user-provided string of 'buildings' actually match "valid" buildings. In order to do this, currently I'm doing:

```
$buildings = $this->_getBuildings();

$buildingIds = array();
foreach ( $buildings as $building ) {
     $buildingIds[] = $building['id'];
}

$valid = true;
foreach ( $userPassedBuildingValues as $value ) {
   if ( !in_array( $value, $buildingIds ) ) {
       $valid = false;
       $this->addError();
   }
}
```

I'm looking for a way to refactor this so I don't have to loop through all the building elements and create a new array each time I do this comparison. Are there any array mapping/searching functions that may make this easier?

I was contemplating refactoring `getBuildings` to have an optional argument to return a list of IDs but this would "plague" the function and I don't think it would be as "pure" as it is now.

**EDIT #1**: First idea was to create a method that took a 'key' and would return a concatenated array of those keys from the array. For instance,

```
$buildings = $this->_getBuildings();

$buildingIds = $this->_getAllValues( 'id', $buildings );

function _getAllValues( $key, $array ) {
   $return = array();
   foreach ( $array as $rowKey => $row ) {
       if ( $rowKey == $key )
           $return[] = $row[$key]
   }
   return $return;
}
```

But perhaps there's a different, cleaner approach? I'd be doing the same type of thing for at least 4-5 different functions.

Note: The depth on the arrays will not be more than one, so no need to worry about deeply nested arrays.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ouzo-goodies](https://github.com/letsdrink/ouzo-goodies) like:

```
$buildingIds = Arrays::map($buildings, Functions::extract()->id);
```

Here are links: [Functions::extract](http://ouzo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/utils/functions.html#extract), [Arrays::map](http://ouzo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/utils/arrays.html#map).

**//EDIT**

Here is two classes which can use as a helper.

```
class Helper
{
    public static function getBuldingIds($buildings)
    {
        return Arrays::map($buildings, Functions::extract()->id);
    }
}

class Helper
{
    public static function getBuldingIds($buildings)
    {
        return array_map(function($building){
            return $building['id'];
        }, $buildings);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's pretty sugary syntax, but can you think of a way that doesn't require including another library? I just would prefer whoever may inherit my project to more easily work with the code vs trying to learn sugary syntax from a 3rd party library. Personally I like that, but not everyone might.

Comment: Regarding creating a `getBuildingIDs` method - the problem is I'd have to create these methods 4-5 times for each of my other functions and this may be too redundant?

Comment: This is little wired that you can include any libraries to your project.
You can create some static method which will be helper and taking buildings as a parameter and extracting `id` from them.